# OnItemClickListener using ArrayAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I want to have an OnItemClickListener for a ListView I create using an ArrayAdapter

This is the code I use to create it:

```
List<Comment> values = datasource.some_search("Wednesday","11");
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I implement onItemClickListener?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am using in my ArrayAdapter and ListView a string of objects.

EDIT 2: More code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        //check if database is populated if NOT, populate with txtToDb();

        if (!datasource.isPopulated()) {
            // Database is not populated so copy it from assets here
            try {
                txtToDb();
                Log.i("Database", "Was not Populated");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Database", "Was not populated: txtToDb(); failed");

            }

        } else {
            Log.i("Database", "Populated");
        }

        //wat to show on screen:
        List<Comment> values = datasource.search("Wednesday","11");


        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

EDIT 3: XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can call setonItemClickListner method for that..

Comment: @piyush- Can you tell me how? How do I create the method that links it with the ArrayAdapter given above?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use OnItemClickListener

```
   ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

When you click on a row a listener is fired. So you `setOnClickListener` on the listview and use the annonymous inner class `OnItemClickListener`.

You also override `onItemClick`. The first param is a adapter. Second param is the view. third param is the position ( index of listview items).

Using the position you get the item .

Edit : From your comments i assume you need to set the adapter o listview

So assuming your activity extends `ListActivtiy`

```
     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Or if your activity class extends Activity

```
     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
     //initialize adapter 
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how this method is linked to the array adapter above? Surely I can't just copy paste this and expect it to work. I'm a relative newbie so please explain a little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: "// assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item" I am assuming here is where I type the code that does something if an item is clicked?

Comment: @AhmedZafar you can do what you intend to do instead of getting the item when you click the row. exactly

Comment: Okay. And how do I link ListView lv with my array adapter? That's what's confusing me. Also will I give the function an input or will it automatically know what I am clicking

Comment: @AhmedZafar there is no need to link anything. shows us more code your activity code

Comment: @AhmedZafar what does your activity class extend `ListActivity` or `Activity` and shows us your xml

Comment: Does "ListView lv = getListView();" automatically link to the listview in that activity?

Comment: Wow okay this works but it crashes on  String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);  so I commented that out and put Log.i("Database", "ITEM CLICKED"); and it does seem to work but the thing is, how do I retrieve data from that click. It has a number stored in it which I want it to call. So the question is that I want to customize this rather than have just one thing happen for every item clicked. Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedZafar show us the number you said string and also post the updated logcat no need for customization or anything.

Comment: Sorry it's not string. I don't remember saying that. Logcat is perfect and says ITEM CLICKED whenever I click an item. In the Adapter are stored Objects with Strings in them. Things like name, contact, day1, from1, etc etc. I want to retrieve these values.

Comment: @raghun- HOLY (@#*$U* IT WORKED! THANKS SO MUCH! I used Comment comment = (Comment) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
              Log.i("Database", comment.getName()); To print out names to the logcat. Thanks! :) This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this way...

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {

          String main = listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand how this method knows that it's linked to the ArrayAdapter above?

Comment: means you want to get value from adapter??

Comment: I have the list which is displayed, store in the ArrayAdapter. When I click an item on the list, I want it to do something. Call a number, to be specific. How can I use this method so that it does that? listView is not something that I have specified in my code, can you please tell me more about how this function works and how I will use it. I am confused.

Comment: And if you are call different thing for different item then use switch case also..

Comment: thanks so much for the reply but I am still confused. Sorry. I have an array adapter declared, and not a listView. Do I need to do something before this method to link the array adapter to the 'listView' that you have show in your method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36115/discussion-between-ahmed-zafar-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: If you have already taken in xml file then find the id of ListView onCreate() method else accroding to Raghunandan you can use that.

Comment: How would you get the string of each textview if there are two textviews in each item. I have a Contacts list that I would like to get the value of the number as well as the name. How would I do this? @PiyushGupta would you be able to help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after the information that your Activity extends ListActivity here's a way to implement OnItemClickListener:

```
public class newListView extends ListView {

    public newListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(
            android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
        //do something when item is clicked

    }

}
```

Comment: Does your Activity extends ListActivity?

Comment: Yes it does! Where do I go from there?

Comment: I use setListAdapter instead of list.setAdapter(--). Should I be using both?

Comment: @toddx- Thanks so much. I need to create a new class for this? And if I do I still do not get how does this class link with my original listview? Please clarify this. And thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using arrayadpter ,using this follwed code i'm able to get items

String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             String string=adapter.getItem(position);
             Log.d("**********", string);

        }
    });
```