# Filtering on a list

Tags: java, android

I have a list of Countries and I am using it as a search, so if I am searching for a specific country, once its found the country I want, I selected it from the filtered list. The problem is, when I select the 112th item on the filtered list, if it is at the top of the filtered list, the result is actually the 1st item on the unfiltered list.

This will be an easier way of explaining it, I've uploaded a video to it which can be found here [Search Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHz8gRk4ip8)

my Adapter for the Search is here:

```
    public Context mContext;
public ArrayList<Countries> countryArrayList;
public ArrayList<Countries> original;

public CountryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Countries> countryArrayList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.countryArrayList = countryArrayList;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return countryArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return countryArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CountryHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.search_results_row_list, parent, false);
        holder = new CountryHolder();
        holder.countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_text);
        holder.countryFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_flag);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CountryHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.countryName.setText(countryArrayList.get(position).getCountryName());
//        holder.countryFlag.setImageResource(countryArrayList.get(position).getImgId());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Countries> results = new ArrayList<>();
            if (original == null)
                original = countryArrayList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (original != null && original.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Countries g : original) {
                        if (g.getCountryName()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            countryArrayList = (ArrayList<Countries>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public class CountryHolder {
    TextView countryName;
    ImageView countryFlag;
}
```

Sorry I forgot where I am actually selecting the country

```
private void setSearchResultsList() {
    final CountryAdapter countryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), controller.getCountriesArrayList());
    countryAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchPhrase);
    countryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            String selectedCountry = controller.getCountriesArrayList().get(+position).getCountryName();
            mISearch.searchResult(selectedCountry);

        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: error is obvious and not in this code ... but in onItemClick ... obviously you are using position to get item from original arraylist ... but it is a wrong way ... the normal way is well documented ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnItemClickListener using ArrayAdapter for ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405299/onitemclicklistener-using-arrayadapter-for-listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once for all the time:
If you are using `AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener`, the right way to get clicked item is such implementation:

```
adapterView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```

`parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` returns `Adapter.getItem(position)` from your adapter used in `AdapterView` (with `setAdapter`)

so for example:

- if you are using `ArrayAdapter<T>` you should cast `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to `T` and use it ...
- for `ArrayAdapter<POJO>` use:

  `POJO item = (POJO)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`
- if you are using `CursorAdapter`

  - `Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`
- if you are using `SimpleAdapter`

  - `Map<String, ?> item = ( Map<String, ?>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

of course it depends on your Adapter implementation ... so you should remeber that Adapter should return the right object with `getItem(position)`

As it is stated in the documentation it apply to: `ListView`, `GridView`, `Spinner`, `Gallery` and other subclasses of `AdapterView`

So in your case the right way is obviously:

```
Countries country = (Countries)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Selvin, Appreciate that! I tried that and that workes wonders as well. It also seems to be the better answer of the 2

Answer (score 0):

do this way

---

add one method in `adapter` class to get current list

```
public ArrayList<Countries> GetCurrentListData() {
        return countryArrayList;
    }
```

---

```
CountryAdapter dcAdapter = new CountryAdapter("whatever your perameter");
    listview.setAdapter(dcAdapter);
    lstDoctorsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            try {
                                Countries countries = dcAdapter
                                     .GetCurrentListData().get(position);
                                // get data from countries model class

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It will not compile because annonymous class ... there is no need for adapter reference in onItemClick ... the parameters passed to this method is all you need ...

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked 100%! I had a method in my controller though that got the list of Countries, but for some reason this didnt work as that was what i was returning