# Why isn't my cursor working in my ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, cursor

I want to replace my EditTexts with the item clicked on my ListView. I used cursor to move along the items on the ListView. However, even when I click the second item on it, the first item shows up instead. What did I do wrong?

Here's my ListView onItemClicked code:

```
lv_people_info.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override           
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            people_info2 = new ArrayList<String>();


            Cursor cursor2 = db.query(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME,// Table
                    allColumns, // The columns to return
                    null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null, // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null, // don't group the rows
                    null, // don't filter by row groups
                    null, // The sort order
                    null); // Limits the number of rows returned by the  query  

            cursor2.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {
                people_info2.add(cursor2.getString(1));
                people_info2.add(cursor2.getString(2));
                people_info2.add(cursor2.getString(3));

                et_name.setText(people_info2.get(0));
                et_amount.setText(people_info2.get(1));
                et_description.setText(people_info2.get(2));

                cursor2.moveToNext();

            }

            cursor2.close();
        }

    });
```

Here is what happens when I click the second row of the ListView:

[image]

Comment: this code should show  **always last** item in the table after **any row click**

Comment: @Selvin the first, actually. the views are set with content from the beginning of the array.

Comment: yeah, you are right ... the whole point is  that there is no use of `int position, long id` passed to the `onItemClick` callback

Comment: Use `setTag()` to bind your primary key to you `ListView` row. In your `ItemClickListener` use `getTag()` and query your db with that id.

Comment: @KNeerajLal seriously ... what for? there is no need for `get/setTag` the answer is for wrong question but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256083/filtering-on-a-list/33256930#33256930

Comment: Yeah, works in this case because he has displayed all item to edit in the `ListView` row.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace my EditTexts with the item clicked on my ListView .

Well, that's what you should do instead of using the cursor. Your listview have been already populated with the data from `Cursor.` So there's really no need to query it again!

Just receive the necessary information in your `onClickListener()` from the row.

You can use `ViewHolder` pattern. Create simple class named `ViewHolder`, keep there references to your name, amount, description fields. Then in your `newView()` method create new ViewHolder and use `setTag()` to attach it to your view.

In `bindview()` bind data to it. Then, in `OnClickListener` use `getTag()` from `view`.

You can see good example here https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Do not query your database in the UI thread! Querying database in OnClick method is a mistake. If after you read the article, you still want to query database, at least use `CursorLoader` or `AsyncTask`.

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED FOR `OnClickListener` as he is using `ListView` not `RecyclerView` ... and ViewHolder should only keep references to the (dums!!!) Views in the row, not data ... and *I want to replace my EditTexts with the item clicked on my ListView .* prolly means: I wana bind data from selected row into EditTexts

Comment: Hi @RexSplode, I'm sorry but I'm very new to this. So after I create the ViewHolder class, how do I attach the data clicked on my ListView into the ViewHolder?

Comment: the data is attached to row  in bindview() method. In your onClick() you simply call getTag() to receive ViewHolder instance. After that you can call viewHolder.textView.getText() to receive the text of a name textView in clicked row. Then, editText.setText(retrievedString);

Answer (score -1):

The below code may work fine..

```
Inside Listview clickevent

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase=myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
String sql=select name,amount,description from yourTableName 
Cursor cr = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Now you add here

```
 people_info2.add(cr .getString(1));
 people_info2.add(cr .getString(2));
 people_info2.add(cr .getString(3));

 et_name.setText(people_info2.get(0));
 et_amount.setText(people_info2.get(1));
 et_description.setText(people_info2.get(2));
```

Comment: [Programming by permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) achivment gain ... this will not even compile cause literal is not in aphostropes ... also such `db.rawQuery` is the same as `db.query` so why it would help?

Comment: Also there are spaces between `cr` and `.getString`. Zero effort in this answer

Comment: better known as `"Billion Monkeys Programming Style".`