# Launch a new activity from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

So I set up a list view which populates itself from an array of strings in the strings.xml file, and I can't seem to figure out how to code it so that tapping/clicking on one of the options in the list starts a new activity. I know that topics for this exist already, but it seems that I'm setting up my listview differently so the solutions presented aren't compatible. Here's my mainactivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
Map<String, Integer> mapIndex;
ListView consoleList;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] consoles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.consoles_array);

    Arrays.asList(consoles);

    consoleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_consoles);
    consoleList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, consoles));

    getIndexList(consoles);

    displayIndex();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

private void getIndexList(String[] consoles) {
    mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < consoles.length; i++) {
        String console = consoles[i];
        String index = console.substring(0, 1);

        if (mapIndex.get(index) == null)
            mapIndex.put(index, i);
    }
}

private void displayIndex() {
    LinearLayout indexLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.side_index);

    TextView textView;
    List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<String>(mapIndex.keySet());
    for (String index : indexList) {
        textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.side_index_item, null);
        textView.setText(index);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        indexLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    TextView selectedIndex = (TextView) view;
    consoleList.setSelection(mapIndex.get(selectedIndex.getText()));
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.tylerfrisbee.gamerguide/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.tylerfrisbee.gamerguide/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your code for [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)?

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18405437/2308683

Comment: as cricket_007 said you must do this on onItemClickListener

Comment: To answer your actual question of "how to start another activity" - Look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on the ListView:

```
consoleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    //do whatever you want to do if you want to start a new Activity:
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

This should populate the `onItemClick` method as soon as you click on the item in the ListView and this should call your onClick method if this is what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think `onClick(view)` should be called. That would throw a ClassCastException if the `ListView` has any other view than a `TextView`

Comment: Oh that's right. I will edit the answer corresponding. Thank you.

Comment: I might be wrong on this one, but `getContext()` should be `MainActivity.this` since it is within an anonymous class and `getContext()` is not a method within `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: getContext() was just meant to be replaced with the context you want to use in this case, however I will change it.

Comment: Is there any other setup code I need to implement first? I can't really describe why I can't get this working, I'm a noob here..getting "cannot resolve symbol" on setOnItemClickListener. Thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: there shouldn't. where were you adding the lines? you probably should implement this in `onResume`.

Comment: I just managed to get it working actually, that cleared everything up. Thanks!