# How to get attribute and image by parsing XML

Tags: android, xml

I am using Android Studio to create an app. I have XML data like this:

[image: XML Data]

I want my first activity to show a list of names of employees. When I click on any name, I want my second activity to show a list of images based on the name I've clicked. How do I do that?

Comment: Use DOM for parsing xml file and Use RecyclerView for listing data after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) will be of great use in this.

> There are two key methods: next() and nextToken(). While next() provides access >to high level parsing events, nextToken() allows access to lower level tokens.
>
> The current event state of the parser can be determined by calling the >getEventType() method. Initially, the parser is in the START_DOCUMENT state.
>
> The method next() advances the parser to the next event. The int value returned >from next determines the current parser state and is identical to the value >returned from following calls to getEventType ().

Here is an example from the link above:

```
public static void main (String args[])
     throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
 {
     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("Start document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
          System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
          System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
          System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
     System.out.println("End document");
 }
```

The question above is a bit broad, but i will try and provide some clues on how to do it:

You should iterate through your data, create a list of Employees [POJOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo), and use that in your [ListView's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) adapter. You can also set an [on click listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405299/onitemclicklistener-using-arrayadapter-for-listview) for each item and then use [an imageview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) to display the images.