# Null Pointer Exception when invoking setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

New to Android and Java and learning by doing but I seem to be missing something fundamental on detecting item clicks in a ListView.

I have an activity that is a couple of buttons with a ListView below them.  Each ListView item has an icon that can be clicked on, that will eventually go to another activity, and a timestamp (currently just indicating the click worked via Toast).  Click detection on the icon is working but I am trying to implement selection of items in the ListView and that is where I am running into trouble.

I have reviewed numerous examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405299/onitemclicklistener-using-arrayadapter-for-listview) and I think I am doing it as prescribed but I am obviously missing something, as I am receiving a runtime exception *"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference:"*

Here is the layout for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.foo.magma.ViewPassagesActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update"
            android:onClick="update"
            android:id="@+id/updateButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:onClick="delete"
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/passagesListView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the layout for an item in the ListView.  As mentioned, it an icon on the left with a timestamp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/curve" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timestamp: "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon">
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="layouttesttime"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="layouttestdate"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/label">
    </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is he onCreate() from my activity, which sets my adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_passages);

    ListView passagesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passagesListView);
    assert passagesListView != null;

    buildPassageList();

    PassagesViewAdapter adapter = new PassagesViewAdapter(this, R.layout.passages_row_layout, passages);
    passagesListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

And here is where I am having the issue.  The OnClickListener for the icon works. My intent is to detect selection of a ListView item so that it can be deleted.  However, when I add the invocation of setOnItemClickListener(), I receive a runtime exception.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class PassagesViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Passage>{

    private int resource;
    private List<Passage> passages;

    public  PassagesViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Passage> passages) {
        super(context, resource, passages);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.passages = passages;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = li.inflate(resource, null);
        }

        Passage passage = this.passages.get(position);

        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setTag(new Integer(position));
        final String positionStr = icon.getTag().toString();

        // This works great!
        icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked on " + positionStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

       ListView passagesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.passagesListView);
       assert passagesListView != null;

       // ** This call results in a runtime error for null pointer reference.
       passagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        time.setText(passage.getPassageTime());
        date.setText(passage.getPassageDate());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because the `View` you have in your adapter represents the `View` you see in the list, not the layout of your `ViewPassagesActivity`. You do not have a `ListView` in your `ListView` items so it cannot be found and `findViewById` returns null. If you move the part where you set the `OnItemClickListener` to the `onCreate` of your `ViewPassagesActivity`, everything should be working fine

Remove this part from your adapter

```
// ** This call results in a runtime error for null pointer reference.
passagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and add it to your Activity's onCreate like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_passages);

    ListView passagesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passagesListView);
    assert passagesListView != null;

    buildPassageList();

    PassagesViewAdapter adapter = new PassagesViewAdapter(this, R.layout.passages_row_layout, passages);
    passagesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ** This call results in a runtime error for null pointer reference.
    passagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Aha.  I get it.  Thanks for the prompt reply.  Moving to OnCreate() worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending your Adapter from BaseAdapter.

This

```
public class PassagesViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Passage>{
```

to this

```
public class PassagesViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

Also your *setOnItemClickListener* needs to be in the onCreate function in your activity, not in the adapter.