# If I use simple adapter to feed the listview and the listview contains textview and button so how can I perform operation on specific position?

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to find the **position** of the view which is the part of the list-view's custom XML file. How can find the position of the views. Can i automatically perform **onItemClick**?

Comment: try implement your own customer adapter where you would be able to handle individual item click in it. also try using recyclerview it is better approach.

Comment: you can simpley get position by this int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnItemClickListener using ArrayAdapter for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405299/onitemclicklistener-using-arrayadapter-for-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face this difficulty. In my case when i click on **textview** which is part of list-view's custom XML file then the position is right, but when i click on the button which is the part of list-view's custom XML file then it always gives first position.

After i have to decided to perform automatic **onItemClick** and store all the values of clicked position into another declared variable which is below.
[See the image i used **kotlin** language instead of java. I stored all the map values into another variable which is declared above with public access specifier.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uNhP.png)

[Now when i perform operation on Button click i use

**lvShayari.performItemClick(v, lvShayari.getPositionForView(v), lvShayari.selectedItemId)**

this statement in which **lvShayari** is listview and **performItemClick()** method perform the **onItemClick** automatically when we clicked on button. Here v is the view, **lvShayari.getPositionForView(v)** method gives the **position** of v in my case it is button.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjOnB.png)

Answer (score 0):

check out below code , hope it will help you:

```
listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

for more Details follow [this](https://grokonez.com/android/kotlin-listview-example-android) link

Answer (score 0):

@Suvidha Malaviya

Make your own custom adapter for your listview with one interface in which there is one method with three parameters namely View, Position, Model class of your list which you are passing in your adapter.

After making this interface initialize that interface in your adapter and set that interface method in your view click event.

Now set this interface in your activity or fragment where you are using your custom adapter and get the value which you want...

For example, see below link in which there is explain [how to use custom listener in list view adapter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/). Here you have to just make your own click listener in which you have to pass three parameters which I have mention above.

Try it. I hope you will resolve your issue...